# Is it possible to both embed and include associated objects with ActiveModel::Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activemodel, active-model-serializers

We are in a weird situation where we have a relied-upon endpoint that both embeds data and sideloads it. I have no idea why it was built this way, and why no one thought `hey, we seem to be sending all of this data twice`, but to divine the reasons of the former stewards of our code is a sisyphean task.

I'm rewriting the currently-manually-built JSON output to use serializers, because deleting useless code is joyful. However, I can't seem to figure out two issues:

1) There does not seem to be a way to embed an object *and* also sideload it. I know I can sideload by setting `embed :ids, include: true`, but this only returns the `ids` of the sideloaded objects from within the parent relation.

2) Is there a way to not set the `embeds` status for every relation? It seems that the only way to set something sideloaded or embedded is that `embed :ids...` line, but that affects *everything* that is a relation. How do I get more granular control over embedding/sideloading?